# Power Apps/D365 and DocuSign Integration - Send Envelope on behalf of others

Tags: docusignapi, powerapps, power-apps-custom-connector

This is my first time posting so apologies if I don't explain things clearly.

I've created a Custom Connector within Power Apps that does an API call to my DocuSign Account. The API call I am currently leveraging is to create DocuSign Envelopes:
**/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes**

Link to DocuSign API Library: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/create/?explorer=true

My issue is that I do not know how create Envelopes on behalf of other DocuSign Users while using the API call within my Connector. Since the Custom Connector required me to log into my DocuSign Account, every time I use the Connector the Envelope generated from the API call gets associated to me (I am able to see it within "Drafts" when I log into my DocuSign).

Sorry if this is a bit confusing. My end goal is to use my Custom Connector and its API calls within a Canvas App. However, I want the Envelopes created not to always be associated to my DocuSign account especially if the Canvas App is used by other End Users.

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks!

Screenshot of Test call:
[Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxWSw.png)

Screenshot of Test Call: [Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxvUE.png)

Screenshot of Envelope within DocuSign Account: [Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvMhu.png)

Comment: Hey, screenshots demonstrating your issue are helpful to include

Answer (score 0):

This is Yara from DocuSign Developer Support.
Since you want to create envelopes on behalf of other DocuSign Users while still using the API call within your connector, you can use the Send On Behalf Of Functionality (SOBO). This functionality allows a single user in an account to authenticate for other members of the account and send fully defined envelopes on their behalf.
Here's a detailed guide on the SOBO functionality: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-soap-api/esign101/auth/send-on-behalf-of/

Comment: Hi Yara! Thank you for responding to my post. I think I am already leveraging SOBO logic. I added some screenshots of my Custom Connector and tests with its API calls to my original post.
My issue is that whenever this API call is made, the Envelope is created within my DocuSign Account. Is there someway to associate the envelope to another DocuSign User dynamically by leveraging API calls? 

Here is the link I leveraged to create the Connector:  https://www.docusign.com.au/blog/get-the-flow-sending-docusign-envelopes-microsoft-power-automate

Comment: Hello, 
Try this POST call to: restapi/v2.1/accounts/<accountID>/envelopes/transfer

with this JSON body:
{"carbonCopyOriginalOwner":false,"envelopeBulkTransferTypeId":"1","envelopeIds":["<envlopeId>"],"toUserId":"<userId>"}